# Isomorphism between algebraic Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a isomorphism between the additive group of real algebraic numbers and the multiplicative group of positive real algebraic numbers, which is order preserving.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any such isomorphism would have to extend to a continuous morphism from the additive group of the real numbers to the multiplicative group of the positive real numbers because the order-preserving condition means convergent sequences get sent to convergent sequences.  Any such morphism is $a^x$ for some positive real $a$, and this is impossible e.g. by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).